# C++ vector(math) destination, check range based on movement

Tags: c++, vector-graphics

I am moving an entity to a new position vector, however when it reaches it's destination, it's jumping around the destination.
I want to check on a range of the destination based on the movement speed, can anyone help with how I could go about this?

Here is the function:

```
void Enemy::onUpdate(Graphics& graphics)
{
        //function called every tick
    Vector dest(190.f, 250.0f);
    Vector destination = dest - posVec;

    Vector normalise = Vector::unitVector(destination);

    mPosVec = mPosVec + normalise * mVelocity;//mVelocity = 4.f

    mX = mPosVec.x;
    mY = mPosVec.y;

        //clamp range
        //if(something)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is `posVec` the current position? Also is `mPosVec` different?

Comment: oh yeah they are the same, i changed it in here and forgot to change all of them, cheers

Comment: mX and mY are ints, It's for blitting to the screen, as that function only takes ints at the minute

Comment: I think it has something to do with the `float` / `int` you have there.

Comment: yeah probably, I'll see what I can do with it, someone suggested, using a circumference around the destination vector. Thanks anyway